# How do I use a structural type with generic parameters?

Tags: scala, generics, structural-typing

I have two case classes

```
case class StringCaseClass(argument: String)

case class IntCaseClass(argument: Int)
```

I want to define a structural type which will match the companion object of both of these

```
type HasApply1 {
  def apply[A, R](argument: A): R
}
```

This will compile fine, but when I try to use it like this

```
def method(caseClass: HasApply1) {
  // whatever
}

method(StringCaseClass)
```

I will get a compiler error

```
found   : StringCaseClass.type
required: WithApply1
            (which expands to)  AnyRef{def apply[A, R](string: A): R}
```

Is there any way of accomplishing this? If I redefine the structural type to have concrete types for A and R it will compile correctly, but then I lose the flexiblity

Comment: For further clarification, I would like to create a method such as this: `def method[A](caseClass: HasApply1, a: A) = caseClass.apply(a)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@aloiscochard's comment is almost there. What he forgot to mention is that case class companion objects *already* implement the appropriate `FunctionN` trait, so you can simply do this,

```
scala> case class StringCaseClass(argument: String)
defined class StringCaseClass

scala> case class IntCaseClass(argument: Int)
defined class IntCaseClass

scala> def method[A, R](caseClass: A => R, a: A) = caseClass(a)
method: [A, R](caseClass: A => R, a: A)R

scala> method(StringCaseClass, "foo")
res0: StringCaseClass = StringCaseClass(foo)

scala> method(IntCaseClass, 23)
res1: IntCaseClass = IntCaseClass(23)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I suppose the real answer to the question the way I asked it is that you cannot do it.. but this works for me

Comment: Wow Miles, that's brilliant.  I didn't have a chance to get back to SO yesterday, but that's way better than what I would have come up with! +1!

Answer (score 3):

In general you should avoid structural typing as it's *very* expensive. The call will be converted into a reflection call because of limitations in the JVM.  When you start using scala 2.10 structural types will result in a warning at compile time (though you could disable that using a flag).

If you're looking into a more general way to add functionality to classes that don't share an inheritance hierarchy you could use Type Classes.

Here's a quick example:

```
trait CanCreateRFromA[A,R]{
    def createNew(a:A): R
}

implicit object CanCreateBlahFromInt extends CanCreateRFromA[Int,Blah2]{
    def createNew(i:Int):Blah2 = new Blah2(i)
}


implicit object CanCreateBlah1FromString extends CanCreateRFromA[String,Blah1]{
    def createNew(s:String):Blah1 = new Blah1(s)
}

case class Blah1(something:String)
case class Blah2(something:Int)

def createRFromA[A,R](a:A)(implicit tc:CanCreateRFromA[A,R])= tc.createNew(a)
```

Then you can call:

```
createRFromA(1) // This gives a Blah2
createRFromA("1") // This gives a Blah1
```

Again I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it probably is possible to do what you want with a type class and it will be much faster.

Comment: A lightweight alternative would be use the type `Function1[A, R]` (or `A => R`) instead of creating the CanCreateRFrom trait.

Comment: @coltfred see my comment on the original post for further clarification of what I am trying to do. I don't mind about the expense of the operation

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass an instance of `StringCaseClass` to your `method`. What you passed there is companion object of `StringCaseClass` (which is automatically generated for case classes).

Try if this works: `method(StringCaseClass("dummy"))`.